# множественная замена текста в БД SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть 1500+ строк, в строке содержится домен, подскажите пожалуйста запрос который удалит интересующий текст, нужно убрать повторяющийся домен https://example.com/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как-то так:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET columnName = SUBSTRING(columnName, LENGTH("https://example.com/"))
```

В принципе вместо `LENGTH("https://example.com/")` можно тупо число вписать хардокодом и всё. Оно характеризует то, с какой позиции брать подстроку

Comment: сработало, только вот остался слеш перед slug /vbulletin-logo-6.html попробовал отдельно слеш убрать, не получилось

Comment: Всё тоже самое надо делать. Только с 1 символа. Или с 0. Не помню с чего там отсчёт ведётся

Comment: есть, благодарю!